# plink を使う際に、 .ssh/config 形式の設定を読み込んでそれから実行できるか

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

plink を用いる際に、 PuTTY で接続情報をセッションとして保存すれば、そのセッション名を指定して

```
plink session-name
```

のようにすると、設定された接続情報で ssh できます。

一方で一般的な ssh コマンドは、接続先情報を `~/.ssh/config` に記述して、その中で設定する Host の設定によって、

```
ssh host
```

を実行すると、 `~/.ssh/config` の、該当 Host の設定に従って ssh できます。

---

質問: plink において、 .ssh/config 形式の設定を利用して ssh を行うことはできますか？

背景: `vagrant ssh-config` で出力された ssh 設定を利用して、 plink の接続を行おうと思ったので、この質問をしています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.ssh/config`は OpenSSH 特有の設定ファイルなので plink では使えません。
WindowsのOpenSSHクライアント (ssh.exe) を使ってください。

OpensSSH のインストールはいくつかバリエーションがあります。
Cygwin、MinGw、Git(msysGit)、などをインストールすると使えるようになります。

また、使ったことありませんが PowerShell で使えるOpennSSHがあるそうです。
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH

Comment: とすると、 mac や ubuntu にデフォルトで入っている ssh プログラムも、 OpenSSH である、ということでしょうか。

Comment: そのはずだったと思います。`ssh -V` で `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014`みたいな感じで表示されると思うので試してみてください。